# how to combine two Maximo animation without repeating from origin

Tags: animation

im trying to combine two animation (to make it simple i duplicate the same animation three times). However, when the second and third animation started , it reset the position of the armature to the original position where the first animation started.

here is a video to explain :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TH4uucxAoxsmUTQiNhzZG6HIR5F1ozhH/view

any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

**Modifying via the graph editor**

If you open the graph editor, you'll probably see something like this:

[image]

where the crenelated parts are the character translation along time.

You can select it and translate it along the Y axis of the editor windows <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>:

[image]

**Shifting the armature (or a parent of it)**

You can also keyframe the armature (or a parent of it) position and set its curve to *"constant"*.
But this is a bit harder to adjust because curves scales and orientation are not necessarily the same.

[image]

**Repeat with offset**

You can also use a *"cycles"* modifier. Though, as there are probably many curves, you'll need to set it a lot of times. And practically, this may be painful.

Comment: thank so much for your help, i have one question remains , how do i parent an object to the pose position (not the armature )

Comment: Your other question? You can enter edit mode for the armature, select a bone that will be parent. Back in object mode, select the object and shift select the armature. Ctrl+P and choose "bone".

Comment: thanks a lot! worked for me